# What is the ideal self hosted search engine?

Tags: search-engines, intranet

I have an internal (intranet) site that is comprised of several blogs and forums, hundreds of static pages, lots of PDF files and several other document types. Its been glued together loosely over the last couple of years and now its my job to maintain it.

I'm looking for a search engine that I can host myself that ideally:

1. Allows for searching the Blog / Forum databases directly if given the database information and tables to search.
2. Handles most text documents (PDF/DOC/ODF)
3. Is open source, or allows access to the source code once purchased

It doesn't matter to me what language or platform it is written in. Normally, I'd just use Google site search, but that's not an option for an intranet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out **[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)**

Written in [Java](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) also available for the [.NET framework](http://lucene.apache.org/lucene.net/)

Here's a CodeProject article that explains how it works and how it's used.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/) before and have been quite impressed.

Answer (score 2):

[SearchBlox](http://www.searchblox.com/) which is based on Lucene may be able to meet your needs. It is free and comes with a crawler.

Comment: free for 25k urls, which is not much for an intranet

Comment: @cweiske Check out Ambar, it's based on ElasticSearch and free. https://github.com/RD17/ambar

Answer (score 0):

> Normally, I'd just use Google site
>   search, but that's not an option for
>   an intranet.

There is in fact the Google search appliance which is the equivalent of Google site search for intranets. However, this is not open source (google site search isn't either though, in case you hadn't noticed.)

Comment: I looked at it. I really want something where I can have access to the code. Its also a little heavy in the budget department.

Comment: In addition to the Google Search Appliance, there is a similar product by "Thunderstone" that's competitive. I've used both in the past. While it may not work for you, thought I'd post for others who stumble on the question.